# how to adjust network speed using Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I'm using fiddler to adjust the speed.

I'm also checking the simulate modem speed option.

but I'm not seeing any changes to my broadband network speed.

Am I missing out on something here?

Any help would be appreciated.

i tried adjusting the speed, but there was no change in the network speed.

```
if (m_SimulateModem) {

        // Delay sends by 300ms per KB uploaded.

        oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "4"; 

        // Delay receives by 150ms per KB downloaded.

        oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "2";
```

Comment: Make sure your applications are using Fiddler, even if Fiddler configures Windows to use it as proxy some applications ignore system proxy settings. Do you see the requests/responses in the main view?